# YouTube Videos in SOTI Surf: black screen only audio

Tags: soti, mobicontrol

Our platform team is using MobiControl to administrate our Handscanners (Zebra TC77). For reasons beyond my understanding we HAVE to use SOTI Surf as default browser in Kiosk mode. But when we open a link with this browser embedded videos from YouTube are running but the video is not showing: only black screen, YouTube controls and audio.
Same happens, when I directly go to YouTube: interface is visible, YouTube controls too, there's audio but only black screen instead of video.

The platform team is at a loss, since our use case is nothing they have been confronted with before. Has anyone else encountered this before? Is there a solution or is this just the way SOTI Surf behaves?

I tried to cross check the settings with common solutions for the no video but audio only issue with YouTube videos. I identified JavaScript as a potential issue, but it's activated.

I also tried to use Chrome instead by calling the link with Intent://URL#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;component=com.android.chrome;end
which is working but opening a regular Chrome Tab but we need to hide the address bar, browser menu, ...

Calling the link via JavaScript, which would allow me to handover some parameters to the browser, doesn't call Chrome because it's not the default browser. At least the way I did it:

```
 function openUrl() { 
         var options = "location=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes"; 
         var theUrl = "<URL>";
         window.open(theUrl, "", options); 
        }
```

The ultimate goal is to open a link on the handscanner in kiosk mode in a browser with no toolbar and no menu which can display YouTube videos.